# Concatenate contents of multiple Exchange resource calendars into XML output (or other export)?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, scripting

Can you think of a way (PowerShell preferably, but open to any suggestion) to grab the contents of a pile of Exchange 2007 resource calendars and then make these available as XML, RSS, or delimited text, or something, that can then be consumed by another application?

__

Clue 1 from the Michigan Powershell Script Club: "You’d have to query via Exchange Web Services, which provides this functionality. I’ve never tried it, but people who have say it’s fairly easy."

Clue 2 from an Exchange admin at a university: "...there’s some functionality in OWA web parts that could potentially called and displayed."

Comment: What version of Exchange?

Comment: It's Exchange 2007.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help - http://powershellneedfulthings.blogspot.com/2009/10/bulk-export-calendars-from-exchange.html.  I think if you change it so that it dumps everything into one CSV file you might be able to do some sorting if you need it and consume the CSV in another app.